# check radio button when the mouse is over it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to check my radio buttons when the mouse is over it without clicking. It is do display photos when. I tried to do this with JQuery but I'm beginner with it.

Comment: show the code you tried? show your code here

Comment: @DanielH Don't ask for code in JS Fiddle. Ask for the code right here in SO. External links may become invalid over time and they are an extra step someone has to go through to provide help. Really, the only time a Fiddle or a CodePen should be used is when the SO snippet environment won't run the code that is being asked about.

Comment: @ScottMarcus sure, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work.

Comment: you might want to think of another element to use than a radio button.  Sounds like it would be an improper use of it, especially since it's unexpected behavior to check a radio by simply hovering over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
   </style>
</head>
<body>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="photo" data-image="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="radio-hover">
    Option - 1
  </label>
  
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="photo" data-image="http://placehold.it/250x150" class="radio-hover">
    Option - 2
  </label>
  
  <br>
  
  
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="photo1" alt="">


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    $(".radio-hover").hover(function(){
      var imageUrl = $(this).data("image");
      $("img").show();
      $("img").attr("src",imageUrl);
    },function(){
      $("img").hide();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the radios listen for `mouseenter` events, at which point you can either trigger a `click` event on the current radio, or explicitly set the radio's `checked` property to `true`. Remember, radios and checkboxes need to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` because in HTML they don't technically have a value, they're a named property only.

```js
$(function() {
  $(':radio').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" value="radio1"><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" value="radio2"><br/>
<input type="radio" name="radio-group" value="radio2"><br/>
```

Comment: thank you! your code helped me so much! I changed it like this
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
  $('.slider input[type=radio]+label').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.slider input').prop('checked', true);
  });
});

but it still don't work well yet. I'll work on it tomorrow

Comment: Are your labels directly after the radio buttons? You didn't provide ANY source code in your question which is why it's been so downvoted. Please update your question with your HTML at least.